# Range of date time compare in R for cutoff

Tags: r, excel, datetime

Good morning, sorry for the simple question, but I'm new to programming r and I don't know how to solve it. I read a csv file with the following data:

```
  smf30jbn jesnum ccode              end_day enddatetime initialtime interface cutoff-original
1 DCDDDP00  14380   Sun 2020-03-15 17:07:181     2020-03-15 17:07:17 IN1233_01        07:00:00
```

I want to get this result:

1. Add a new column with the name of the cutoff that has this format: `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`
2. Get the difference between the new cutoff column and the `enddatetime` column

   With the following rules to manage the 24 hours:

   - case1) if cutoff time> = 06:00:00 and <= 23:59:59 on the same day
   - case2) if cutoff time> = 00:00:00 and <= 05:59:00 +1 day

     example:
     Day 16/03/2020 if cutoff = case1 the new column cutoff = 16/03/2020 + cutoff-original (hh:mm:ss)
     Day 16/03/2020 if cutoff = case2 the new column cutoff =
     3/17/2020 + cutoff-original (hh:mm:ss)

Excuse me for my English . Thanks for all the help you can give me.

Comment: you might want to have a look at this package for dealing with date and time variables: https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have already tried using lubridate but without success